# Disable Wacom Finger Touch in Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: touchpad, wacom

I've reinstalled my system and what used to be 16.04.1 is now 16.04.3.

Before the reinstall, I disabled the Wacom Touch using the following script:

```
WACOM_TOUCH=`xinput --list --short | grep -m1 "Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger touch" | cut -f2 | cut -d= -f2`  
xsetwacom --set "$WACOM_TOUCH" Touch off
```

After installing 16.04.3, it doesn't work anymore because `Finger touch` is renamed to `Pad pad`:

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Pen stylus     id: 8   type: STYLUS    
Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Pad pad        id: 10  type: PAD       
Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Pen eraser     id: 14  type: ERASER
```

However, even when I disable `Touch` on `Pad pad`, touch is still enabled and I keep accidentally firing touch events. In fact, I can disable them for all devices, without an error thrown:

```
$ xsetwacom --set 10 Touch off
$ xsetwacom --set 8 Touch off
$ xsetwacom --set 14 Touch off
```

Touch just doesn't turn off.

Is anything else changed? **How do I turn off touch?**

---

#### Some logs

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep wacom
wacom 0003:056A:00D1.0007: hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Mouse [Wacom Co.,Ltd. CTH-460] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input0
wacom 0003:056A:00D1.0008: hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Wacom Co.,Ltd. CTH-460] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/input1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall note that there is at least in Xubuntu this 'Mouse and Touchpad' window in which you can disable Wacom touch Finger. It was a lifesaver for me :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I got followings:

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen stylus       id: 11  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pad pad          id: 12  type: PAD       
Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger touch     id: 13  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen eraser       id: 14  type: ERASER    
Wacom Intuos Pro M Pen cursor       id: 15  type: CURSOR
```

I can get the current vaule with the following:

```
$ xsetwacom --get "Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger touch" Touch
on
```

Disable the finger touch:

```
$ xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger touch" Touch off
```

Confirm:

```
$ xsetwacom --get "Wacom Intuos Pro M Finger touch" Touch
off
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't have the "finger touch". What would be the difference between _pad pad_ and _finger touch_?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.5.

Comment: I couldn't find any document with detailed description about Wacom settings on Ubuntu yet.